# Find exact string in tuple

Tags: python, tuples, lookup

I am using python to access results from another program. The program has a specific module in order to so. Unfortunately I do not understand the tuple format ("stuff") that comes out as a result.

I am familiar with looking up keys/values in dictionaries, but not how this would work. I am new to tuples and I am using 2.7.5 - any help would be great!

```
>>> import OrcFxAPI
>>> model = model.OrcFxAPI('C:\#17.sim')
>>> stuff = model.objects
>>> print stuff
(<General Data: 'General'>, <Environment Data: 'Environment'>, <Line Contact Data: 'Line Contact Data'>,  <Vessel: 'vesselA'>, <Vessel: 'vesselB'>, <Line: 'A'>, <Line: 'B'>, <Line: 'C'>, <Line: 'D'>, <Line: 'E'>, <Line: 'F'>)

>>> print type(stuff)
<type 'tuple'>

>>> print map(type, stuff)
[<class 'OrcFxAPI.OrcaFlexObject'>, <class 'OrcFxAPI.OrcaFlexObject'>, <class 'OrcFxAPI.OrcaFlexObject'>, <class 'OrcFxAPI.OrcaFlexVesselObject'>, <class 'OrcFxAPI.OrcaFlexVesselObject'>, <class 'OrcFxAPI.OrcaFlexLineObject'>, <class 'OrcFxAPI.OrcaFlexLineObject'>, <class 'OrcFxAPI.OrcaFlexLineObject'>, <class 'OrcFxAPI.OrcaFlexLineObject'>, <class 'OrcFxAPI.OrcaFlexLineObject'>, <class 'OrcFxAPI.OrcaFlexLineObject'>]
```

I want to lookup instances of Line, and output 'A','B','C','D','E','F':

```
>>> for thing in stuff:      
        if isinstance(thing, Line) and thing.name == 'C':          
            line_c = thing 
            break
        else: 
            raise ValueError('No Line C in stuff!')  

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'Line' is not defined
```

Comment: is line a separate class and you have some instances of it in your tuple?  If so, you can just filter the tuple with `isinstance`:   `lines = [x for x in stuff if isinstance(x, Line)]`

Comment: It would really help to give us enough code to understand your question, and a concrete example of what you want to do and what the expected result should be. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for guidance.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell from your vague question, but I think what you want is something like this:

```
for thing in stuff:
    if isinstance(thing, OrcFxAPI.OrcaFlexLineObject):
        print thing.name,
print
```

Or, equivalently:

```
lines = (thing for thing in stuff 
         if isinstance(thing, OrcFxAPI.OrcaFlexLineObject))
names = (line.name for line in lines)
print ' '.join(names)
```

---

If you're looking for the `Line` object that has a specific name, that's just as easy:

```
for thing in stuff:
    if isinstance(thing, OrcFxAPI.OrcaFlexLineObject) and thing.name == 'C':
        line_c = thing
        break
else:
    raise ValueError('No Line C in stuff!')
```

… or:

```
line_c = next(thing for thing in stuff 
              if isinstance(thing, OrcFxAPI.OrcaFlexLineObject) and thing.name == 'C')
```

---

But in general, you don't want to do this like of "type switching" code. It would be better to store this information in some way that kept all the lines separate from all the other things. Maybe this:

```
{'general': <General Data: 'General'>, 
 'environment': <Environment Data: 'Environment'>, 
 'line contact': <Line Contact Data: 'Line Contact Data'>, 
 'code checks': <Code Checks: 'Code Checks'>, 
 'shear7': <SHEAR7 Data: 'SHEAR7 Data'>, 
 'vessels': (<Vessel: 'vesselA'>, <Vessel: 'vesselB'>), 
 'lines': (<Line: 'A'>, <Line: 'B'>, <Line: 'C'>, <Line: 'D'>, <Line: 'E'>, <Line: 'F'>)
}
```

And then it would be a matter of just using a dict lookup (which you already know how to do) and iterating over a sequence (which you already know how to do):

```
for line in stuff['lines']:
    print line.name,
print
```

---

Or, maybe even better, use a class instead of a dict, so the object has a `lines` attribute that you can use like this:

```
for line in stuff.lines:
    print line.name,
print
```

Comment: Thanks @abarnert. Unfortunately I continue to get this message for most of those options: '    NameError: global name 'Line' is not defined'

Comment: @AllieC: I have no idea what object you have that's printing as `<Line: 'A'>`. I assumed it was an instance of some type `Line` that you've defined somewhere—or, if not, that _you_ would know what it was. When you don't give us nearly enough information to be able to debug your code, you have to expect that we're going to end up guessing at everything, and often guess wrong. Again, read the SSCCE link from my comment to understand how to write a more answerable question.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I added more to the question to hopefully help explain the issue a bit better.

Comment: @AllieC you may wish to include in your question, what `print type(stuff)` shows, and what the result of `print map(type, stuff)` shows...

Comment: @AllieC: Thanks for the edit. Apparently the type of those "Line" things is `OrcFxAPI.OrcaFlexLineObject`. Maybe the OrcFxAPI library uses some kind of base `OrcaFlexObject` class that has a method line `isline`. If so, you can use that. If not, just use `OrcFxAPI.OrcaFlexLineObject` instead of `Line` in the code. I've updated my answer to show that. (But again, if you can avoid this kind of type switching, you should.)

Answer (score 0):

OrcFxAPI objects of type `OrcaFlexObject` and those with that base e.g. `OrcaFlexLineObject` have attributes called `typeName`, `Name` and `type` (the upper/lower cases of those is correct and a proper PITA). So, if I understand your question you can do this:

```
>>> import OrcFxAPI
>>> model = model.OrcFxAPI('C:\#17.sim')
>>> lines = filter(lambda o: o.typeName=="Line",model.objects)
>>> for line in lines:
        print line.Name

A
B
C
D
E
F
```